# Trying to find or match an Old Allen Bradley R450 J-Type potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer, vintage

I'm looking for any information on how to replace or repair this potentiometer. It's an AB R450 J-type potentiometer on a Brent ceramic wheel from the early 70's, I believe. I cannot find anything online that matches it.

The problem being it is stuck at high speed only with only a slight variation when I turn it back and forth in its range. It is originally embedded in the electric foot pedal of a ceramic wheel. You press it from "off" to high speed depending on what you are doing with clay on the potter's wheel.

Does anyone know how to match these to a newer version? I have seen a couple on eBay that are similar but don't carry the exact description to match, like this one:

[image]

This picture is of the broken R450.

[image]

Any help from you electrical pros?

Comment: Potentiometer specs include: Resistance, taper (linear or log, this would most likely be linear), power, shaft diameter, shaft length. I believe that *Type J* refers to their line of high-quality pots. For a panel mount pot such as this, the mechanical dimensions are fairly standard. You need to determine the resistance, maybe it is written on the side, or maybe you can measure it if it hasn't completely failed.

Comment: Can you get to the other connection (assuming there is one) and measure the element resistance?  Failing that, pop the back off the pot and try to measure it.

Comment: Top photo appears to be 50 ohm. Bottom photo *might be* a special-order from Allen Bradley, hence your difficulty finding a match. What exactly **R450** means is unclear, and its taper might be linear or logarithmic. Do be careful about mounting - these **type J** have 0.25" dia. shafts, but variations of length (some are very short, with a locking nut).

Comment: @glen_geek:  it looks like 500 Ohms to me...

Comment: @PeterBennett I notice that Allen Bradley part #'s use three-digit value, with last digit as 10's multiplier. If so, 500=50 ohms, 501=500 ohm, 502=5000 ohms....

Comment: @glen_geek - *ohm* is spelled out, so it's plain ohms IMO, 500. A part number would have more letters/digits and it wouldn't have *ohm* after it.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably similar to [this](http://precisionelectronics.com/files/Series-RV4-Military.pdf) kind of military-style potentiometer.

You'll need to measure the bushing and shaft length and body size to ensure it will fit mechanically. The shaft is probably 6.35mm diameter (1/4"). You can hacksaw the shaft off if it is too long.

The taper is *probably* linear, and it's probably about a 2W pot, but it's important to get the resistance value at least more-or-less correct.

Measuring the resistance of the entire element would give an answer to that. If the pot does not have 3 terminals you still may be able to pop the back cover off and poke at the element ends with a multimeter to get the resistance value. It's not very critical, probably within 10% or 20% is fine, but available resistances vary over many orders of magnitude.